# Change group with chown in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, permissions, chmod, dscl

Trying to change the group for a file on OSX to `root`, keep getting an illegal group name error though.
Looked around and all the demos match what I'm using. Am I missing something here?
Tried to create a group with dscl as well with the same result

Command: `dscl . -create /Groups/root`

Command: `sudo chown root:root $file`

Error: `chown: root: illegal group name`

Comment: There is more to creating entries with `dscl` then just creating the entry in `/Groups` you also need to set up the `PrimaryGroupID` and maybe some other attributes. There is no `root` group by default, i think what you want is `wheel` or `admin`.... unless you want to introduce a group of `root` on your own that is.

Comment: @prodigitalson Yeah you were right, changed the `dscl` command the following and it worked fine.
`sudo dscl . -create /Groups/root PrimaryGroupID 100`

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue (macos 10.12.x) I needed one final command for the initial command to work and no longer throw the

> illegal group

error.

```
dscl . -create /Groups/groupName GroupMembership userName
```

I had done the PrimaryGroup command which didn't work until the command above was added.